# About TSC acronym pronunciation

Tags: pronunciation, acronyms

How would you pronounce TSC acronym ?
tē ĕs sē ?
or most probably people would use a word like pronunciation 
Tis´ic ? :-(

Comment: They might also pronounce it like "tisk"

Answer (score 1):

When seeing it for the first time, 99% of speakers would say Tee, Ess, See.

If the people who invented the acronym wished it to be pronounced as a word they would have to make this clear to others.

Comment: If entire nations have failed to impose  on the English language their views regarding how a word should be pronounced, mere inventors stand no chance.

Comment: Forget nations.  Entire generations of grammar teachers have failed in the task.

Comment: It's not the inventors who impose pronunciation, it's the users. And since there may be multiple phrases with the same abbreviation, the common pronunciation may depend on which phrase it's being used for.